# Why does i18next work with some languages ​and not with others?

Tags: javascript, react-native, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using i18next and when i call the changeLanguage function with the languages **'es'** or **'en'** it seems to work perfectly, but when i call it when another language **'de'** **'fr'** **'it'** or whatever, it doesn't works and it goes to the fallbackLng.
It's kind of weird because with two languages works perfect, but the other three languages doesn't works

This is my *i18n.ts* file

```
import i18n from 'i18next';

import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

const frenchTranslatorObject = require('../assets/locales/fr.json');
const spanishTranslatorObject = require('../assets/locales/es.json');
const englishTranslationObject = require('../assets/locales/en.json');
const germanTranslationObject = require('../assets/locales/gr.json');
const portugeseTranslationObject = require('../assets/locales/pt.json');
const italianishTranslationObject = require('../assets/locales/it.json');

export default i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    resources: {
        es: {
            translation: {
                'landing.main.title': 'en SPANISH',
            },
        },
        en: {
            translation: {
                'landing.main.title': 'EN ENGLISH',
            },
        },
        fr: {
            translations: {
                'landing.main.title': 'en FRANCES',
            },
        },
        de: {
            translations: {
                'landing.main.title': 'EN ALEMANNNN',
            },
        },
        it: {
            translations: {
                'landing.main.title': 'EN ITALIANO',
            },
        },
        pt: {
            translations: {
                'landing.main.title': 'EN PORTUGUES',
            },
        },
    },
    lng: 'es',
    fallbackLng: ['en', 'es', 'fr'],
    compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
        format: function (value, format, lng) {
            if (value && format === 'uppercase') {
                return value.toUpperCase();
            } else if (value && format === 'lowercase') {
                return value.toLowerCase();
            } else if (value && format === 'capitalize') {
                return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
            }

            return value;
        },
    },
});

i18n.on('languageChanged', (lng) => {
    console.info('callback log that triggers when language change', lng);
});
```

and I call the function like this: i18n.changeLanguage('de');

***Debug info***

In the console when i trigger the changeLanguage('de') in debug mode it seem to change it:

i18next: languageChanged de

i18n.language // this prints 'de'

i18n.getDataByLanguage('es') // and this returns the DE translation object

and it says "i18next::languageUtils: rejecting language code not found in supportedLngs: dev"

If anyone sees any errors that can tell me, I will be grateful

Comment: What is logged to the console when setting debug: true?

Comment: In the console when i trigger the changeLanguage('de') in debug mode it seem to change it :

i18next: languageChanged de

i18n.language // this prints 'de'
i18n.getDataByLanguage('es') // and this returns the DE translation object